# How to make "nohup ./script.sh & disown" working in post-receive git hook?

Tags: git, bash, shell, githooks, nohup

I expect that the script called with

```
nohup ./script.sh & disown
```

will be executed in background and it's output won't be seen while pushing.
But I see the output and I have to wait a delay. Here are the contents of the called script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test'
sleep 5
```

How to make it run as a detached process from my git hook script?
Thanks

## Update

I've understood that I need no `nohup`... For some reason it prevented running my script in background (and maybe disowning it too). So I've got the following string in my hook, and it's working now:

```
./script.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
```

Thanks to @CharlesDuffy for pointing out uselessness of nohup (in this particular case) to me.

Comment: `nohup` doesn't do anything you can't do without it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, sorry, could you clarify what you mean

Comment: I mean that everything `nohup` does your shell can do built-in without any silly external command that creates `nohup.out` files everywhere if you aren't careful about how you use it.

Comment: ...well, not *quite* anything -- you can't use the TIOCNOTTY ioctl, but that only matters for programs that explicitly open `/dev/tty` -- meaning that they're trying hard *not* to be detached. Generally speaking, any piece of software that does that is going to have a way to override the behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your script to detach itself, consider:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ignore HUP signals
trap '' HUP

# redirect stdin, stdout and stderr to/from /dev/null
exec >/dev/null 2>&1 <&1

# run remaining content in a detached subshell
(
  echo 'test'
  sleep 5
) & disown
```

---

Alternately, you can perform these operations from the parent:

```
(trap '' HUP; ./yourscript &) >/dev/null <&1 2>&1 & disown
```

Comment: ...btw, if this doesn't work as-is, try logging `ls -l /proc/self/fds >/path/to/logfile` to find any other handles on your TTY that might need to be closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I actually want to run a detached script from post-receive git hook, which is a separate, parent, script. I don't think I need to write a self-detachable script

Comment: Updated appropriately.